# Why isn't data showing when I drill through from parent to child report in Cognos?

Tags: cognos

I have a parent report and a child report.  The child report contains a conditional block, which renders the appropriate list (a, b, c) as selected in the prompt (static choices).  When I drill through on the List Key (we'll say a, b, c) it works fine, and the correct list conditionally renders.  However, when I add another condition, the data no longer displays.  Do you know why this is?

The child should recognize that there I'm passing "a", then render list "a", and then also pass the other condition I specified to list "a".  I have a feeling it's going wonky because of the conditional block, however I am not certain.

Comment: Can you clarify? What kind of additional condition are you applying? Is it a required or option filter? Can you supply some more info about the logic applied to the conditional rendering?

Comment: I am referring to the data item that I'm passing in the drill-through.  The child report is set up with static choices so that if I select "A" then it runs list A from the conditional block, if I select "B" then it runs list B, etc.  I can pass "A", or "B" from the parent to the child and render the correct list from the child's conditional block.  However, if I tell it to pass another data item in the drill-through (one that isn't contained as a static choice in the child report), then it won't pass it along.

Comment: Link to the conditional block instructions- 
 http://businessintelligence.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/cognos10-l/conditional-block-in-cognos-10-4319677.

I did implement a workaround.  I split the four lists out in to four separate reports, and I can now easily pass multiple data items via the drill-through.  However, it would still be nice to know how to contain them in one list with a conditional block.  My assumption is that you can only use a conditional block with static prompt choices as seen in my link, which appears to limit the drill-through to those data items.

Comment: There's no reason you can't use a single drill-through target that adapts. I've done it many times myself. I wish I had a clearer picture of what's happening as I'm sure there would be a way to accomplish what you want without resorting to four reports.

Comment: I'll try to create a more simplistic report and see if perhaps it was something else that was throwing my report off.  Basically, I start with a repeater table that contains a pie chart, and then I want to pass the value from the repeater table, and then a value from the pie.  The value from the repeater table is what renders the list in the target report, and I"m struggling to pass the value from the pie to the rendered list.  It could be related to the way I set up the conditional blocks, as seen in the link above.

Comment: The simplistic report functioned properly, so there will be more investigation on my end on how to fix the actual report.